# Does iOS 12.2 support GPS for PWA?

Tags: ios, gps, progressive-web-apps

I'm about to build a PWA, but it requires a use of GPS. I know Android supports that, but have no clue if that will work for iOS users.
Does anyone know whether iOS 12.2(current last version) supports GPS for PWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **100% sure you can use GPS in iOS PWA**

**Abilities of PWAs on iOS**

With the Web Platform on iOS you can access:

- **Geolocation**
- Sensors (Magnetometer, Accelerometer, Gyroscope)
- Camera
- Audio output
- Speech Synthesis (with headsets connected only)
- Apple Pay
- WebAssembly, WebRTC, WebGL as well as many other experimental
  features under a flag.

**Limitations**

Compared with native iOS apps:

- The app can store offline data and files only up to **50 Mb**
- If the user doesn’t use the app for a few weeks, iOS will free up the
  app’s files.
- No access to  Bluetooth, serial, Beacons, Touch ID, Face ID, ARKit,
  altimeter sensor, battery information
- No background processing
- No access to private information (contacts, background location) and
  also no access to native social apps
- No access to In App Payments
- No Push Notifications, no icon badge or Siri integration

[Progressive Web Apps on iOS are here - Medium](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7)

[ref1](https://medium.com/@onejohi/introducing-geolocation-in-your-pwas-65713faba51a)
[ref2](https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/pwa-myth-busting-a891/)

Comment: These are about PWA for mobile in general. The most interesting thing whether GPS will work on iOS

Comment: Limitation on PWAs on iOS also include access to camera when installed on Home Screen.  Camera works fine in a browser (Safari - Chrome is still a bit iffy), but if you install the same PWA onto the home screen the camera does not work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants a detailed review of PWAs on iOS 12.2, please check [this article from Maximiliano Firtman on Medium](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945) (published on March, 26th - 2019). In short, Apple Web Kit team created a new framework for PWAs. It doesn't rely anymore on Safari. The main drawback I experienced is that updates through service worker seems not to work anymore as well as offline browsing when the page includes lazy loaded pictures.